# How to select sub-arrays from an n-dimensional array n-agnostically?

Tags: r, multidimensional-array

**Short version:**

How does one programmatically select sub-arrays from an *n*-dimensional array when *n* is arbitrary?

(If the short version of this question is clear enough, feel free to skip the rest of this post.)

---

Suppose that `A` is an array such that `dim(A)` is the vector of positive integers (*d*<sub>1</sub>, *d*<sub>2</sub>, …, *d*<sub>*n*</sub>), with *n* > 2.

For example:

```
> d <- 5:2
> set.seed(0)
> A <- array(runif(prod(d)), dim = d)
```

Here the array `A` corresponds to the definition given earlier, with *n* = 4, and *d*<sub>k</sub> = 6 - *k*, for *k* ∈ {1, 2, 3, 4}.

---

Then, if 1 ≤ *i* ≤ *d*<sub>1</sub> and 1 ≤ *j* ≤ *d*<sub>2</sub>, the expression `A[i, j … ]` (where `…` is a placeholder for *n* - 2 commas) evaluates to an (*n* - 2)-dimensional array.

To continue the previous example, if we take *i* = 3 and *j* = 2, my notation `A[i, j … ]` would denote the (*n* - 2 = 2)-dimensional array shown below:

```
> A[3, 2, ,]
           [,1]      [,2]
[1,] 0.94467527 0.4785452
[2,] 0.01339033 0.7111212
[3,] 0.02333120 0.1293723
```

---

More generally, if
1 ≤ *k*<sub>1</sub> < *k*<sub>2</sub> < … < *k*<sub>*m*</sub> ≤ *n*
and
1 ≤ *i*<sub>*r*</sub> ≤ *d*<sub>k<sub>*r*</sub></sub>, ∀*r* ∈ {1, … *m*}, then an expression of the general form

```
A[ … i1 … i2 … … im … ]
```

...(where the `…`'s are placeholders for sequences of indices *i*<sub>k</sub> and commas), evaluates to an (*n* - *m*)-dimensional array.

For example,

```
> d <- c(4, 2, 5, 4, 2, 7, 3)
> set.seed(1)
> A <- array(runif(prod(d)), dim = d)
> A[3, 1, 4, , 1, 6, ]
          [,1]       [,2]       [,3]
[1,] 0.5320469 0.77282382 0.18034186
[2,] 0.6817434 0.08627063 0.77227529
[3,] 0.8572805 0.32337850 0.63322550
[4,] 0.6555618 0.20578391 0.01257377
```

---

Now, one can write out expressions like `A[i, j … ]` and
`A[ … i1 … i2 … … im … ]` in full (i.e. filling in all the … placeholders) only if one knows *n*.

Of course, when one is working *interactively*, one usually knows (or can easily find out) what *n* is, and can use this knowledge to decide how many commas to insert in, e.g., `A[i, j … ]`.  This is not the case, however, when one is writing code to work with multi-dimensional arrays of any number of dimensions.

---

How would one express selections such as `A[i, j … ]` and `A[ … i1 … i2 … … im … ]` when one does not know *n*?

Comment: If `A` is given, you can get "everything" from `dim(A)` (in your case 5 4 3 2) and `n=length(dim(A))` (in your case 4). What else do you need?

Comment: @Christoph I think he is placing a restriction on being able to determine `n`, including the use of `length()`. Is that right @kjo?

Comment: It's not clear what input you imagine passing to the function...

Comment: @MichaelKirchner: it's ok to determine `n` programmatically, but at that point (i.e. at run-time) it's too late to ***write*** in one's code an expression with the right number and placement of commas.  Unless, I suppose, one creates an R-expression synthetically at run-time, and evaluates it dynamically.  I wouldn't know how to do this, though.

Comment: Anyway, if you specify an interface for the function, the function itself follows pretty naturally, I guess... You could, for example, have a two column matrix: one col for dim indices (subscript in i_k) and the other for selections (values in i_k)... But really, that's up to you and ought to be specified in your post.

Comment: @Christoph: The best I can do to answer your question is to offer the following exercise: write a function `f` that takes as argument a multidimensional array `A` of arbitrary dimension *n* > 2, and returns a list of all the (*n* - 2)-dimensional subarrays `A[i, ..., j]`, where `i` and `j` range over all valid subscripts for the first and last dimensions of `A`, respectively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps this will work for you:

```
func <- function(ary, ..., drop = TRUE) {
  d <- length(dim(ary))
  dots <- list(...)
  if (length(dots) > d) stop("incorrect number of dimensions")
  rest <- rep(TRUE, d - length(dots))
  do.call(`[`, c(list(ary), c(dots, rest, drop = drop)))
}
```

Using your data:

```
d <- rev(2:5)
set.seed(0)
A <- array(runif(prod(d)), dim = d)
```

You normally need to know how many commas to include for the correct dimensionality:

```
A[3,2]
# Error in A[3, 2] : incorrect number of dimensions
```

This function "fills in" the rest of it for you:

```
func(A, 3, 2)
#            [,1]      [,2]
# [1,] 0.94467527 0.4785452
# [2,] 0.01339033 0.7111212
# [3,] 0.02333120 0.1293723

func(A, 3)
# , , 1
#           [,1]       [,2]      [,3]
# [1,] 0.3721239 0.21214252 0.6470602
# [2,] 0.9446753 0.01339033 0.0233312
# [3,] 0.1765568 0.59956583 0.8612095
# [4,] 0.7176185 0.79423986 0.3162717
# , , 2
#           [,1]       [,2]      [,3]
# [1,] 0.2936034 0.71251468 0.3531973
# [2,] 0.4785452 0.71112122 0.1293723
# [3,] 0.8394404 0.05893438 0.7317925
# [4,] 0.8643395 0.45527445 0.7155661
```

It correctly handles all dimensions:

```
A[3,2,1,1]
# [1] 0.9446753
func(A, 3, 2, 1, 1)
# [1] 0.9446753
```

And errors similarly with too many dimensions:

```
A[3,2,1,1,1]
# Error in A[3, 2, 1, 1, 1] : incorrect number of dimensions
func(A, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1)
# Error in func(A, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1) (from #4) : incorrect number of dimensions
```

**Edit**: and the part that I missed. In order to catch blanks, we need to have a little fun.

```
func <- function(ary, ..., drop = TRUE) {
  d <- length(dim(ary))
  dots <- as.list(match.call()[-(1:2)])
  if (length(dots) > d) stop("incorrect number of dimensions")
  pf <- parent.frame()
  dots <- lapply(seq_along(dots), function(i) {
    x <- dots[[i]]
    if (missing(x)) TRUE else eval(dots[[i]], env = pf)
  })
  rest <- rep(TRUE, d - length(dots))
  do.call(`[`, c(list(ary), c(dots, rest, drop = drop)))
}
```

I had a simpler version of this function (without the `lappy`), but it tended to fail if any of the positional arguments were variables vice literals.

```
d <- c(4, 2, 5, 4, 2, 7, 3)
set.seed(1)
A <- array(runif(prod(d)), dim = d)
A[3, 1, 4, , 1, 6, ]
#             [,1]      [,2]      [,3]
# [1,] 0.007668596 0.1818094 0.3278203
# [2,] 0.286473525 0.4119333 0.4825088
# [3,] 0.008869468 0.4767760 0.7649491
# [4,] 0.330141563 0.3438217 0.8710419
func(A, 3, 1, 4, , 1, 6)
#             [,1]      [,2]      [,3]
# [1,] 0.007668596 0.1818094 0.3278203
# [2,] 0.286473525 0.4119333 0.4825088
# [3,] 0.008869468 0.4767760 0.7649491
# [4,] 0.330141563 0.3438217 0.8710419
i <- 3
func(A, i, 1, 2+2, , 1, 6)
#             [,1]      [,2]      [,3]
# [1,] 0.007668596 0.1818094 0.3278203
# [2,] 0.286473525 0.4119333 0.4825088
# [3,] 0.008869468 0.4767760 0.7649491
# [4,] 0.330141563 0.3438217 0.8710419
```

Comment: OP has an example with blanks in the middle `A[3, 1, 4, , 1, 6, ]`. Is that covered?

Comment: @r2evans: FWIW, the case Frank refers to was in the original post.

Comment: Yes, I'm seeing it now, fix in 30sec

Comment: Ok, so a little more than 30sec ... how now, kjo?

Comment: Thanks.  I learned tons from studying your answer.  I did not know about the `[` function, nor that one could mix boolean and integer subscripts (so that `TRUE` behaves like an omitted subscript).  With this knowledge, I think that ``func <- function (array_, subscripts_list) do.call(`[`, c(list(array), subscripts_list))`` would be good enough.  E.g. my last example would be written `func(A, list(3, 1, 4, TRUE, 1, 6, TRUE))`.  IOW, this 2-argument form of `func` ...

Comment: ...is just syntactic sugar that abstracts away the `do.call` on ```[```.  This makes it more convenient in situations in which the subscripts are available only in the form of a list of unspecified length.